# SonarQube analysis with msbuild proj files

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube

I want to run a SonarQube analysis on msbuild proj files.
The build consists of one .proj file. This file builds several other .proj files.
When I run the build, SonarQube prints this error message:

```
The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
Possible causes:
1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 14.0 and 15.0 are supported
3. The begin, build and end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
4. None of the analyzed projects have a valid ProjectGuid and you have not used a solution (.sln)
```

I checked and the last point is probably the problem.There is no .sln but each of the called .proj files has a Guid added, but not the top one. (it worked fine with .njsproj files previously, which had a guid)

Project Guid is provided like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ProjectGuid>{B1E36758-8A06-4793-A7D2-216DE578732D}</ProjectGuid>
    </PropertyGroup>
    ....
</Project>
```

I also tried without curly braces.

I'm not really sure what sonarqube is expecting.
Is SonarQube working with .proj files?

Comment: Why not define a solution project referring to the projects to be analyzed especially for the sonarqube analysis?

Comment: The Scanner for MSBuild knows how to handle C# and VB.NET projects. What type of projects are you analysing?

Comment: we used .njsproj and that worked. Now we want to use proj files, but sh that doesn't work